# Can't figure out how to run an Electron Linux build

Tags: linux, electron, linux-mint

I have a game that I've built with Javascript and I'm using Electron 5.06 to package it. Both the mac and windows builds work without any issues. I need it to run as an arcade machine for an exhibit, so I wanted to build a Linux machine to run it off of. I installed Mint 19.1 and built the Linux release, but I can't figure out how to run it. When I click on what should be the executable, it says:

"The file "game" has no known programs associated with it. Use the Open With dialog to pick a program to open it with."

I've been searching but I can't seem to find a way to run it. Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/modify-file-permissions-with-chmod/#making-a-file-executable

Comment: That's perfect, thanks @KenSharp :)